# std::getline ignores first character when taking multiple string inputs and string subscript goes out of range when not using cin.ignore()

Tags: c++, string

when i use cin.ignore() i can take all inputs but i'm missing the first character of all strings after the first input.

If I don't use cin.ignore() I'm getting a string subscript goes out of range run time error

Here's the code for reference

```
std::vector<std::string> input;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::string lines;
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::getline(std::cin,lines,'\n');
        input.push_back(lines);
    }
```

Comment: THe information that you gave is not sufficient. So, Icannot answer

Comment: Provide a [mcve], including the precise info what keys to press!

Comment: There is something wrong in the rest of your code.

Comment: If you need to `ignore()` once, perhaps put it _before_ the loop. Or at the end of some previous input using `operator>>`?

Comment: `std::cin.ignore()` says to read a character from `std::cin` and ignore it. That's why the first character is disappearing. Take it out, find the source of the actual problem, and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "getting a string subscript goes out of range run time error"? I comment out the code"`std::cin.ignore();`", the program run properly. The function `getline` will discard the char '\n'.

I test these codes you provided, if I comment out cin.ingnore, it run properly. Here is code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> input;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::string lines;
        //std::cin.ignore();
        std::getline(std::cin, lines, '\n');
        input.push_back(lines);
    }
    for (auto s : input) {
        cout << endl << s;
    }
}
```

Maybe you should examine your codes, and find if there are some other bugs.

Comment: Actually for the for loop's i<5, i was taking 5 as inout from user using cin. So i wasn't able to take 5 inputs for the input vector. Any idea how i can take 5 as an integer input before the for loop starts?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to get the number of cycles from user, and then read strings? My suggestion is that you can use cin.get(), which can discard a char from input stream. Like this:

`int main() {
 std::vector<std::string> input;
 int n;
 cin >> n;
 cin.get();
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
  std::string lines;
  //std::cin.ignore();
  std::getline(std::cin, lines, '\n');
  input.push_back(lines);
 }`